# How to serve multiple SPA in nestjs using fastify

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-fastify

The configuration mentioned below works absolutely fine with express but it is giving error when used with fastify.

```
export const serveStaticModule_one: ServeStaticModuleOptions = {
    rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'one')
};

export const serveStaticModule_two: ServeStaticModuleOptions = {
    rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'two'),
    renderPath: '/two'
};

export const serveStaticModule_three: ServeStaticModuleOptions = {
    rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'three'),
    renderPath: '/three',
    serveStaticOptions: {
        index: 'client.html'
    }
};
```

| package used | version |
| --- | --- |
| @nestjs/platform-fastify | 8.2.3 |
| @nestjs/serve-static | 2.2.2 |
| fastify-static | 4.5.0 |

Exact error is *The decorator 'sendFile' has already been added*
I tried passing these object to single `ServeStaticModule.forRoot()` and to multiple, but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by creating new type.

```
type FastifyServeStaticModuleOptions = _ServeStaticModuleOptions & {
    serveStaticOptions: {
        decorateReply: boolean;
    };
};
```

then i created object like this:

```
export const serveStaticModule_one: FastifyServeStaticModuleOptions = {
    rootPath: join(process.cwd(), 'one'),
    serveStaticOptions: {
        decorateReply: false
    }
};
```

It worked perfectly after this.

Comment: I have a very similar issue after creating the type like you mentioned, the error goes away but only one SPA (default one) is working. `export const serveStaticModule_one: FastifyServeStaticModuleOptions = {
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'customer'),
  serveStaticOptions: {
      decorateReply: false
  }
};`

`export const serveStaticModule_two: FastifyServeStaticModuleOptions = {
  rootPath: join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'admin'),
  serveRoot: '/admin',
  serveStaticOptions: {
      decorateReply: false
  }
};` Finally added them in the import section separately.Any idea?

Comment: i will try to recreate this situation tomorrow.... however i think issue is with serveRoot or renderPath... I am always confused with them! can you try to fiddle with these options?

Comment: I have looked into them and `serveRoot` is the one which I should be using. This indicates the path under which the SPA app will be served. `renderPath` (set to `*` by default which means all the paths) is concatenated with the `serveRoot`. when set to *, module returns index.html file in response.